# sequelize query not responding

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am running a raw sequelize query on around 2.3 million rows of data. when I do that, I never get to point where I see "after query". I only see "before query". This suggests me that My query never gets executed. I waited a long time (~10 minutes) to see if it gets executed and I get not error message even after catching the error by using catch function. I confused what happened to the query. In addition, I tried to run the query locally to see how long it takes and it takes just about 5-10s to execute. This suggests me that my query doesn't take a lot of time.

```
/*
 *  Define the Model/Table in database
 */
var TriactaCarma = sequelize.define('triacta_carma',{
    time_stamp:{
        type:Sequelize.DATE(6),
        field: 'time_stamp',
    unique: true
    },
    file_name:{
        type:Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'file_name',
    },
    SN:{
        type:Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'SN',
    unique:true
    },
  Ch1:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch1'
  },
  Ch2:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch2'
  },
  Ch3:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch3'
  },
  Ch4:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch4'
  },
  Ch5:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch5'
  },
  Ch6:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch6'
  },
  Ch7:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch7'
  },
  Ch8:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch8'
  },
  Ch9:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch9'
  },
  Ch10:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch10'
  },
  Ch11:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch11'
  },
  Ch12:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch12'
  },
  Ch13:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch13'
  },
  Ch14:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch14'
  },
  Ch15:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch15'
  },
  Ch16:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch16'
  },
  Ch17:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch17'
  },
  Ch18:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch18'
  },
  Ch19:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch19'
  },
  Ch20:{
    type:Sequelize.DOUBLE,
    field:'Ch20'
  }
},
{
  timestamps:false,
  freezeTableName: true
});
TriactaCarma.removeAttribute('id');

var sequelize = new Sequelize('ptls','root','ODYSSEY99GRANITE',{
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql',
  logging: false,
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  }
});

var max_dials_row_query = sequelize.query("select * from triacta_carma where time_stamp = (select maxdate FROM (select max(time_stamp) as maxdate from triacta_carma) As A) order by SN ASC" ,{model: TriactaCarma, raw:true});
    console.log("before query");    
    max_dials_row_query.then(function(max_dials_rows){
        console.log("after query");
    });
```

Comment: Depending on your indexes this query could be very slow - how fast is it if you execute it directly?

Comment: 5-10 seconds only